# Passing script to psql in Excel 2013

Tags: psql

I can open the psql shell and access my nfldb data base from Excel:

```
Sub atest()

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "cmd /c psql nfldb nfldb"
```

And go to the shell and extract info from the table 'team' in database nfldb to the file 'teamNames' with:

```
nfldb=> \copy (SELECT * FROM team) TO 'C:\temp\teamNames.csv' With CSV
```

My question is how can I run the entire code from within Excel so that the nfldb database is opened AND the rows from the 'team' table are saved to the file 'teamNames'

How do I combine both codes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs help with this, I resolved the issue myself after much trial and error.

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "cmd /c psql -U nfldb -f C:\Python27\writeTeams.sql"
```

Will open the nlfd database in a psql shell and run the script contained in the file 'writeTeams.sql'